# I wish to delete from all the SQL tables that are included in the joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an error stating that there is incorrect syntax near the key word INNER. I wish to delete from all tables included in the statement as they are all constraints related to the table Session.

```
   DELETE FROM Session INNER JOIN
   Booking ON Session.SessionID = Booking.SessionID INNER JOIN
   BookingChild ON Booking.BookingID = BookingChild.BookingID INNER JOIN
   Reservations ON Session.SessionID = Reservations.SessionID INNER JOIN
   ReservationChild ON Reservations.ReservationID = 
   ReservationChild.ReservationID INNER JOIN
   SessionResources ON Session.SessionID = SessionResources.SessionID 
   INNER 
   JOIN
   SnackSession ON Session.SessionID = SnackSession.SessionID INNER JOIN
   SessionSpeaker ON Session.SessionID = SessionSpeaker.SessionID
   WHERE Session.SessionID = 8
```

Comment: Check out ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you must create foreign key with CASCADE action. After this you can delete row only first table, relation data will delete automatically!
Good luck!

Comment: You *can* do this, and it's a good idea. But it's not essential.

Comment: But you must check every query for database integrity,You can save your data in text file instead DB, and will make all function by hand,  but i do not understand for what?

Comment: Thanks i have added This onto all the constraints I wanted affected and it works as I wished.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment:

FWIW, I find this easier to read:

```
DELETE 
  FROM Session s
  JOIN Booking b
    ON s.SessionID = b.SessionID 
  JOIN BookingChild bc
    ON b.BookingID = bc.BookingID 
  JOIN Reservations r
    ON s.SessionID = r.SessionID 
  JOIN ReservationChild rc
    ON r.ReservationID = rc.ReservationID 
  JOIN SessionResources sr
    ON s.SessionID = sr.SessionID 
  JOIN SnackSession x
    ON s.SessionID = x.SessionID 
  JOIN SessionSpeaker y
    ON s.SessionID = y.SessionID
 WHERE s.SessionID = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

List the tables after the `DELETE`:

```
DELETE s, b, bc, r, rc, sr, ss, ssp
  FROM Session s JOIN
       Booking b
       ON s.SessionID = b.SessionID JOIN
       BookingChild bc
       ON b.BookingID = bc.BookingID JOIN
       Reservations r
       ON s.SessionID = r.SessionID JOIN
       ReservationChild rc
       ON r.ReservationID = rc.ReservationID JOIN
       SessionResources sr
       ON s.SessionID = sr.SessionID JOIN
       SnackSession ss
       ON s.SessionID = ss.SessionID JOIN
       SessionSpeaker ssp
       ON s.SessionID = ssp.SessionID
 WHERE s.SessionID = 8;
```

This is described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) under **Multiple-Table Syntax**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It comes up with further syntax errors when I add more than table after the keyword DELETE. How can i get past this?

Comment: @OisinTunney I cannot replicate that observation. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)